# How to align two objects to the center of the Imageview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I would like to align two of my `TextViews` based on the `Imageview`. How would I be able to achieve that `gravity:center` effect on these `TextViews` responsively?  I have tried making the adjusting the margins but then it doesn't work properly since the different phone will have different resolutions and screen sizes so it appears to be distorted on other phones.
Here is what I am trying to do:
[See the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST8lE.png)

Code I tried (Constraint Layout is in AndroidX) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/Constraintlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="82dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/photo" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="82dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/photo" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="58dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="420dp" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="128dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="420dp" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="226dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="420dp" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="296dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="420dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Constraintlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/photo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/photo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/Constraintlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="82dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="82dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView1" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView1" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView1"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView1" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Good approach than mine!!

Comment: Really good answer but I needed both of them to dynamically move to the center since both of my textviews have different text. I will upvote this answer as soon as I get 15 rep. Thanks for helping me and other people.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with Linear layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_person_pin"
                android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_person_pin"
                android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This a xml code

Comment: I need to use a ConstraintLayout. Sorry for not marking your answer as the right one. Thanks for your help. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Ohh. okay. not problem. Your appreciation is motivating me.

Comment: I am really thankful it does motivate you. Your answer is still correct so I will still upvote on your answer once I reach 15 reputation points. Thanks so much.